# How to navigate from Source Code Editor in Visual Studio for Mac to Xamarin API documentation?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, documentation, visual-studio-mac, code-editor

In Visual Studio for Windows, in C# editor, when you type a name of a method and press on F1, while the cursor is on the method for example WithLuninosity as below

```
var color = Color.FromRGB(100, 100, 100);
var color.WithLuminosity(.75);
```

a browser would open with MSDN documentation for the method. 
Or it used to be the case at least for a subset of framework class library.

Is it possible to achieve the same behavior with Visual Studio for Mac for Xamarin API or at least for .NET or .NET Core Framework class library?

Answer (score 0):

you can use "control + space" to view details about the method or "Command + D" to go to declaration and from there you will see the name of the class and the name of the method which will sometimes have decent documentation or you can search more using those values

Comment: Good tips, thanks Ali123. I am looking for "F1" type behavior though.